# Adding text to a third column of a csv file

Tags: sed

I have a data file I need to add text to the 3rd column using sed. My current data looks like this:

```
0001   2345    103 Jane   Doe
0002   4567    103 Jane   Doe
0003   4578    105 John   Doe
0004   5678    103 Jane   Doe
```

I need it to look like:

```
0001   2345    103061321 Jane   Doe
0002   4567    103061321 Jane   Doe
0003   4578    105061321 John   Doe
0004   5678    103061321 Jane   Doe
```

How Can I do this using SED?

Comment: You should reformat to show line breaks and commas, if they're there as implied by the 'CSV' in the question.

Comment: When you say "csv" - does the "c" in your case mean "comma" or "character"? If it's "comma" then please [edit] your question to show commas between fields in your sampleinput/output, if it's "character" then please [edit] your example to tell us what that character is (looks like it may be a tab but idk). Also explain in your question why you specifically want to use `sed` for this when other tools may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "0001 2345 103 Jane Doe 0002 4567 103 Jane Doe 0003 4578 105 John Doe 0004 5678 103 Jane Doe" > test
sed -i 's/ 103 / 103061321 /g' test
cat test
```

reuslt:
0001 2345 103061321 Jane Doe 0002 4567 103061321 Jane Doe 0003 4578 105 John Doe 0004 5678 103061321 Jane Doe

Answer (score 0):

`sed -E 's/ +/061321&/3' file`

This replaces the 3rd occurence of whitespace with `061321[whitespace]` ... effectively adding 061321 to the end of the 3rd column of space-separated data.

- `sed -E` -- extended regex to allow using unescaped `+` in regex
- `/ +/` match one or more spaces
- `/061321&/` replace with 061321 and `&` - what was matched
- `s///3` - do the replacement only for the 3rd match on each line

Above assumes space-separated because of the poor formatting in the OP.   If the data is comma-separated as implied by 'CSV', then it's simply this:

`sed 's/,/061321,/3' file`

... that replaces the 3rd comma on each line with `061321,`

Comment: Perhaps *do what you mean* `sed 's/\S*/&061321/3' file` ?